# Who to count column C with allready condition from column B

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

I need help with counting in column C.

Condition for Column C19 it should look like this:
Ok, search entire column B with criteria "Company1", then look at entire column C (
with the already given criterion from column B), and count the fields that have the number 1 (not to count blank fields).

**I did the manual filling in table for example only.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do this.

1. COUNTIFS

To do this how you asked (i.e. counting the 1s), you can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,$B19,$C$2:$C$17,1)
```

This formula will count the rows in the main table whose value in column B matches the value in column B next to the formula and whose value in column C is 1.

However, counting 1s is the same as summing them, so you could just as well use:

2. SUMIF

   =SUMIF($B$2:$B$17,$B22,$C$2:$C$17)

This will sum column C in the main table for all the rows where the value in column B matches the value in column B next to the formula.

[image]

Personally, I would suggest you use a Pivot Table, as it will offer a lot more flexibility in the long run.

3. PivotTable

You can insert a pivot table by selecting any cell in your main table of data then using Insert > Pivot Table on the ribbon.

[image]

You would then just add Company to the rows area and Sum of Status to the Values area.

[image]